# changing the src of iframe not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am trying to create an iframe widget for some portion of my page. but if I navigate inside the iframe, the src of iframe is not changing. I need the actual URL of the page inside the iframe:

I tried:

```
var iframe_url = $('#iframe_tag').attr('src');
```

but i am always getting the initial src of iframe.

Comment: If the iframe is in a different domain, the original page can no longer manipulate it.

Comment: @Barmar i am creating this widget so that other pages can use some portion of page as widget. but generating widget goes in my page which means, same domain. only after generating, they can use it, then i dont need the urls..

Comment: You said the user navigates inside the iframe, I thought they might be navigating to a different domain.

Comment: @Barmar yeah, user sets up his widget on his own but on my page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the domain within the iFrame is the same as the page domain, you won't be able to do this as it violates XSS (Cross Site Scripting) rules.

If it *is* the same domain then you could use:

```
var iframe_url = $('#iframe_tag').contents().get(0).location.href;
```